# Backslash or Forward Slash in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word

I'm trying to open a file in Qt.I used double back slash in this function

```
doc->dynamicCall("Open(QVariant)", "E:\\QT\\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\\My Question.doc")
```

and it works. However, my directory variable's absolute path returns this, which has forward slash:

```
"E:/QT/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/My Question.doc"
```

and It doesn't work. Error says: " Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?" I tried everything and it only works with double back slash.

[image]

I do know that I have to escape `\` as `\\`, but how do I write this function using my variable ?

Comment: What happens if you simply use forward-slashes in your code?

Comment: It doesn't work. They couldn't find my file.

Comment: Then perhaps your path is wrong in some way. Like misspelled. It's also usually a sign of something wrong if you have to use absolute path names.

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't misspell anything. Would you mind taking a look at the image and maybe figure out what's going on ?

Comment: In general, use forward slashes in Qt code, in code and project files. Convert only when required by Windows specific interface, as explained in the answer.

Comment: even Windows accept forward slash as separators except in a few APIs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#MS-DOS.2FMicrosoft_Windows_style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`toNativeSeparators`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators) function may help you. Since you are on Windows it will replace forward slashes into backward slashes.

Code is like that:

```
string path = "E:/QT/build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/My Question.doc";

doc->dynamicCall("Open(QVariant)", QDir::toNativeSeparators(path));
```